# eval() - syntax error

Tags: javascript

this code produce an syntax error.. but I can't figure out what is wrong?

```
alert(eval('('+this.responseText+')'));
```

EDIT:

```
      var _this = this;
        this.resource.open('POST', uri, true);
        this.resource.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        this.resource.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4){
                _this.clear_timeout();

                if(_this.loader){
                    Loader.dstr();
                }

                if(_this.rtn_func){
                    _this.rtn_func(eval('('+this.responseText+')'), _this.rtn_obj, _this.rtn_scope);
                }
            }
        };
        this.resource.send(get_str);
```

Comment: probably, your response text is not valid javascript...

Comment: What is the value of responseText?

Comment: yes of course! :D make an answer

Comment: whats the content of this.responseText ?

Comment: why do you need to alert evaluated value of a string ? Why not just alert the string ?  and What is the value of this.responseText here ?

Comment: Eval is not good, instead of passing raw JS code pass only data then have the logic in the code reading that data.

Comment: @shadow wizard: what can I do instead of eval()? I don't follow you

Comment: it is used to retrieve data fom a ajax request

Comment: @clarkk let us know what you have there (edit your question with the value) and explain what you're using it for, and we'll try to figure some alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check whether or not `responseText` is *actually* valid Javascript. Are you sure you didn't want to just *display* the string rather than execute it:

```
alert(this.responseText);
```

I should tell you that, unless you have *total* control over where this `responseText` is coming from, that's a hole big enough to fly an C130 aircraft through :-)

Answer (score 1):

_this.rtn_func(eval('('+ this.responseText + ')'), _this.rtn_obj, _this.rtn_scope);

The eval is directly execute the script. Such as u have Response like  12 + 3 + 4

its form

```
eval('(12 + 3 + 4)')
```

this should be work. Are u try like that

Other wise if response text as return function name or else some string data its show error

```
eval('(formdata())')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a= eval("("+this.responseText+")");
 alert(a);
```

Try the above code part. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Bracket is the cause. Try this.

```
alert(eval(this.responseText));
```